Entering the UK by air and leaving by train?
Is it an issue if you enter the UK by air and then leave by train on a Eurostar? I am just hoping that the departure is properly recorded with UK immigration and there is are no problems in entering next time.

No, you will be fine, your exit will be recorded
While the UK doesn't have routine physical exit checks, every transport company must send Advanced Passenger Information to UK Visas and Immigration. Which contain :


Full name
Date of birth
Gender
Nationality
Travel document type
Travel document number
Travel document country of issue
Travel document expiry date


API that you need to submit before you even are issued your train/airplane ticket (you aren't issued your train ticket before you have filled the form on Eurostar website)

On leaving the UK by train I have gone through exit checks. I kind of remember having my passport scanned by an UK border officer before the French passport check, I am sure that UK officer looked at all passports.

@Willeke It happens sometimes but not always.  The important point is that the OP does not need to worry if it does not happen.

I'll be the pedant and state that being issued a ticket doesn't mean you were on the train.  Thus, there would have to be another way of recording that Elvis has actually left the country via Eurostar.

@PeterM True. But I would like to think that I'm not the first one to do that. So "hopefully" it'll be fine?

@justa.human I agree that there has to be a mechanism of ensuring that you left the UK, but IMHO simply buying a ticket isn't it, but I don't know what is.

@PeterM On Eurostar, your ticket is scanned at least 2 times (the same as any plane boarding pass) + the same would happen on a plane, buying a plane ticket is not a sure way you will leave the UK either. The fact that you are immigration-wise in France after passing the controls means that you will be assessed for.

@NicolasFormichella If the scanning of the ticket is what triggers the recording of exiting the UK, then that information is missing from your answer as you only talk about buying a ticket.

@PeterM I have no idea how that work, but that would be the logical thinking, same as with a plane

Taking the Eurostar is very much like taking a plane.  Too much so for my liking.  It negates one of the reasons that I like trains.
